# MFC: How to draw in a static text

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, draw, invalidation

I try to draw in a static text control named IDC_RESULT.When I click the OK button, the static text will display different picture according to the shape I selected.So I declare three bool variable: isLine ,is Rect and isEllipse, everytime when I choose Lien radio box, I make the bool variabel isLine be true and the others be false, the same as Rectangle and Ellipse.

This is my code:

```
void CDrawDlg::OnPaint()
{

    CWnd* pWnd = (CWnd*)GetDlgItem(IDC_RESULT); 
    CPaintDC dcPaint(pWnd);
    CPen pen(PS_SOLID,2,RGB(0,0,0));   
    dcPaint.SelectObject(&pen);

    CRect  rect;
    pWnd->GetClientRect(&rect);

    if(isLine)
    {   
        dcPaint.MoveTo(10,150);
        dcPaint.LineTo (350,150);

    }

    if(isRect)
    {
        dcPaint.Rectangle(50, 100, 300, 200);
    }

    if(isEllipse)
    {
        doSomething;
    }

    ReleaseDC(&dcPaint);

    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); 

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

    int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
    int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
    int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

    dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);

}
else
{
    CDialogEx::OnPaint();
}
}
```

And the function below associate with the OK button:

```
void CDrawDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
     Invalidate(false);
}
```

The question is: How to erase the line in the static text control when I select Rectangle and click the OK button to draw a rectangle,but I can't erase the line.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to [Invalidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ax04k970.aspx) (`bErase`) controls whether or not the background within the update region should be erased. Since you passed `false` it isn't. Pass `TRUE` instead.

As an aside, you should use `TRUE`/`FALSE` instead of `true`/`false` as arguments to MFC methods. Even though the types are compatible they are still different.